# How many ways to distribute M different objects to N places where each places can receive from 0 to M objects?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Here, assume $M > 1$

There are 3 cases

```
1. M < N
2. M = N
3. M > N
```

Each places can receive from 0 to M objects.

EDIT: example

```
M:1,2,3

N:5
```

Some possible combinations:

```
1,2,3,0,0

{1,2,3},0,0,0,0

{1,2},0,0,0,3

....
```

Here, each M components are different, so

$1,2,3,0,0 \neq 2,1,3,0,0$

But,

$\{1,2,3\},0,0,0,0 = \{2,1,3\},0,0,0,0=\{3,1,2\},0,0,0,0=...$

Therefore, once we consider more than 1 objects together, we do not consider the order of the objects in that particular group.

Repetition is not allowed.

Comment: Why are the 3 cases different?

Comment: mathSE reviewers will want you to edit your query to show your work.  Re David Cheng's comment, which I agree with, please see https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/.

Comment: @user2661923 I just realized my mistake, it's distinct objects. Then it's simply $N^M$

Comment: @DavidCheng Is the betting window open?  Technically, you have a point, but I don't think that that was the point of the question (i.e. **meta-cheating**).

Comment: Request clarification - is putting the 1st object in Place-1, the 2nd object in Place-2 considered the same or different from putting the 1st object in Place-2 and the 2nd object in Place-1?

Comment: @user2661923 these 2 cases are different

Comment: @DavidCheng thanks, my blindness.

Comment: @user2661923 More clarification: 1,2,3,0,0 is different from 2,1,3,0,0 but {1,2,3},0,0,0,0 =  {2,1,3},0,0,0,0

Comment: I'm going to be signing off soon.  I suggest that you think about exactly what determines whether one placement of M objects is or is not the same as another placement of M objects.  Be **very precise**, with a complete set of rules, so that there is absolutely no confusion.  Then **edit your query** to put these clarification rules in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distributing M (different) objects to N (different) places/bins, repetition allowed, is equivalent to filling M (different) positions from N (different) choices, repetition allowed.

By the multiplication principle, there are $N^M$ ways this can happen.

A concrete example:
there are $4^7$ ways for $7$ prizes to be distributed among $4$ participants, and there are $7^4$ ways for $4$ prizes to be distributed among $7$ participants.

P.S. On the other hand, distributing M *identical* objects to N (different) places/bins, repetition allowed, is a different story.

Comment: The repetition is not allowed here. If one object is placed in one of the places it can not go into any other places for that sequence.

Comment: @Rel_Ai Yes, your characterisation is consistent with my answer. The phrase "repetition allowed" is ambiguous, and in my answer's context means that each bin/place can be repeatedly filled (naturally by different objects). Each object, unlike Schrodinger's cat however, can go only into a single bin, not multiple bins.

Comment: So are you suggesting this solution N^M when M = N?

Comment: @Rel_Ai Yes -- and the relative sizes of $N$ and $M$ are irrelevant;  there are $N$ possible placements for Object 1, $N$ possible placements for Object 2, and so on, until finally still $N$ possible placements for the $M^{th}$ object. I've just added an example in the answer.

Comment: correction to my first comment: ..."repetition allowed" is ambiguous, but in this context usually means that each *bin* can repeatedly accept (different) objects -- not that each object has repeated/multiple occurrences...

Comment: Wow, @ryang your answer sheds light on a similiar question I tried to solve and did not success. The moderator did not understand my doubts and deleted my question which is similar to the one you solved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @StatsCruncher Am always happy to of help; thanks for your message!

Comment: It felt quite frustrated when both I tried to solve a problem independently but in vain and moderators deleted my question. Appreciate your sharing and kindness. You deserve praise.

Comment: @ryang I just log into and read your comment. The recent discussion which was closed before reopens. Thank you for your reminder and also the useful material for discussion on probability. Apprecitate it as usual.